# How to use the moment library in React Bootstrap table's column definition?

Tags: momentjs, react-bootstrap-table

My code looks as following:

```
const columns = [{
  dataField: 'Id',
  text: 'Order ID'
}, {
  dataField: 'Date',
  text: 'Date'
}, {
  dataField: 'Total',
  text: 'Total'
}];
```

And it displays date in React Bootstrap table. But, the date is in Json format that I don't need.

I've tried to use the moment library to format date in this way:

```
const columns = [{
  dataField: 'Id',
  text: 'Order ID'
}, {
  dataField: '{moment(Date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}',
  text: 'Date'
}, {
  dataField: 'Total',
  text: 'Total'
}];
```

But, the date column is empty.

How can I use the moment library to format the dates for columns in React Bootstrap table's library? Or there is some another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`column.formatter`](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columnformatter-function) can help you. There's a online demo: [this](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Column%20Formatter&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

Comment: The solution (part 1): function dateFormatter(cell) {
  return (
    <span>{moment(cell).format("DD.MM.YYYY h:mm")}</span>
  )
}

Comment: The solution (part 2): const columns = [{
  dataField: 'Id',
  text: 'Order ID'
}, {
  dataField: 'Date',
  text: 'Date',
  formatter: dateFormatter
}, {
  dataField: 'Total',
  text: 'Total'
}];

Answer (score 0):

Here are the sample code in rendor method

```
render () {
        let columns = []
        columns = [
         { name: 'createAt',
        displayName: 'my-Date',
        dataFormat: function callback (cell, row, rowIndex, colIndex) { moment(cell).format('DD.MM.YYYY h:mm') },
        hideFilter: true,
        isKey: true,
        width: '140'
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

i find a way hope you like this...

```js
import moment from "moment";

const Column = [
  {
    Header: "name",
    accessor: "name",
  },
  {
    Header: "ticker",
    accessor: "ticketref",
  },
  {
    Header: "Date",
    accessor: (data) => moment(data.traded_on).format("L"),  // you can pass your date as props and manupulate accordingly..
  },
  {
    Header: "Qty- Quantity",
    accessor: "quantity",
  },
  {
    Header: "Price",
    accessor: "price",
  },
  {
    Header: "Amount",
    accessor: "settlement_amount",
  },
];

export { Column };
```