# Error displaying dates from database in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm developing an application in React.Js.

When I select and save the dates using `react-date-picker`, saved well in the database. But when I show them with `react-bootstrap-table-next` and `react-bootstrap/Table`, don't show correctly.

[image]

For `react-date-picker`:

```
...
<DatePicker onChange={d => setDt(d)} value={date} />
```

For `react-bootstrap-table-next`:

```
<BootstrapTable
  bootstrap4
  keyField="id"
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  pagination={paginationFactory(options)}
 />
```

For `react-bootstrap/Table`:

```
{
  array.map(item => {
    return <tr>
             <td>{item.id}</td>
             <td>{item.date}</td>
             <td>{item.hour}</td>
           </tr>

  })
}
```

It seems to be a problem in how it reads the date value.

How can I solve this, suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the locale information between the database and the client? You may need to perform a datetime conversion if they differ?

Comment: Hello @UncountedBrute! Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, it could be that. How do I do it?

Comment: You could try [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment/)

Comment: Hello @Mike K! Thanks for your answer. How do I implement it?

Comment: @bonnegnu there are loads of ways of checking timezones, it depends on factors like what OS you are running and what distribution. Best thing to do, is check what timezone your PC is running, then remote into the server where the database is running. You then need to find out how to get the timezone based on what OS/Distribution that server is running.
Once you know that information, you'll be able to come up with a plan on how best to correct the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found temporarily (maybe that's the way to do it), was to use [moment](https://momentjs.com/), as suggested in [How to use the moment library in React Bootstrap table's column definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278910/how-to-use-the-moment-library-in-react-bootstrap-tables-column-definition)

I have to format the cell:

```
moment(cell).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

**EDIT**: use [dayjs](https://day.js.org/)

Comment: moment.js is deprecated. they are suggesting to use another library. I found github.com/iamkun/dayjs is pretty good and small library.